# Where to find good documentation on extending Opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am a beginner to Opencart. I am studying capabilities and features of opencart opensource solution.
I have successfully installed opencart on my pc. now I am trying to write my own controller to get a better idea of how to extend opencart. 
My next step would be writing a complete extension for opencart. 
can someone please specify some good documentation or tutorial on extending opencart.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru/13484904#13484904

Comment: OpenCart was actually  very poorly documented. Especially the extending with mods (OCMOD, VQMOD). That said the developers did a great effort to make code readable and understandable. On the other hand systems as Prestashop are terrible code quality. So... If you understand MVC you should be able to understand Opencart Code. If you don't understand MVC -- Learn Codeigniter(there are tons of videos). CodeIgniter is not Opencart but Opencart is very similar in structure to Codeigniter. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official documentation
http://docs.opencart.com/developer/module/

Unofficial help
http://opencart.hostjars.com/blog/3 and http://opencart.hostjars.com/blog/34